# Logging and deque operation problems in Tensorflow Android Speech Recognition Sample

Tags: android, tensorflow, speech-recognition

I'm studying tensorflow speech command sample. 
The Android codebase I use is the same on [tensorflow GitHub android sample](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android) and mainly focus on [SpeechActivity.java](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/android/src/org/tensorflow/demo/SpeechActivity.java) and [RecognizeCommands.java](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/android/src/org/tensorflow/demo/RecognizeCommands.java). I didn't change anything except logging messages.

As far as I know,

(1) [SpeechActivity.java](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/android/src/org/tensorflow/demo/SpeechActivity.java) will pass model referred result (`outputScores`) and `currentTime` to `recognizeCommands.processLatestResults` to do posterior smooth.

```
// Run the model.
inferenceInterface.feed(SAMPLE_RATE_NAME, sampleRateList);
inferenceInterface.feed(INPUT_DATA_NAME, floatInputBuffer, RECORDING_LENGTH, 1);
inferenceInterface.run(outputScoresNames);
inferenceInterface.fetch(OUTPUT_SCORES_NAME, outputScores);

// Use the smoother to figure out if we've had a real recognition event.
long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
final RecognizeCommands.RecognitionResult result =
recognizeCommands.processLatestResults(outputScores, currentTime);
```

(2) in ProcessLatestResults(), `previousResults` is used to store output score which was inferred in recent 500 ms (`averageWindowDurationMs` == 500) and `averageScores` would be the final score we want/use in the future.

```
// Add the latest results to the head of the queue.
previousResults.addLast(new Pair<Long, float[]>(currentTimeMS, currentResults));

// Prune any earlier results that are too old for the averaging window.
final long timeLimit = currentTimeMS - averageWindowDurationMs;
while (previousResults.getFirst().first < timeLimit) {
  previousResults.removeFirst();
}

...

// Calculate the average score across all the results in the window.
float[] averageScores = new float[labelsCount];
for (Pair<Long, float[]> previousResult : previousResults) {
  final float[] scoresTensor = previousResult.second;
  int i = 0;
  while (i < scoresTensor.length) {
    averageScores[i] += scoresTensor[i] / howManyResults;
    ++i;
  }
}
```

My problems/questions are

(1) While the for loop is calculating the average, `previousResult.second` value read from each item is identical. However, it is not possible. My question is did I miss something in logging information so that print out the wrong `previousResult.second` value? or those scores array is truly identical?
Here is how I log:

```
Log.d("tmp", "start average");
// Calculate the average score across all the results in the window.
float[] averageScores = new float[labelsCount];
for (Pair<Long, float[]> previousResult : previousResults) {
  final float[] scoresTensor = previousResult.second;
  Log.d("tmp", "previousResult("+previousResult.first+"): ["+Arrays.toString(previousResult.second)+"]" );
  int i = 0;
  while (i < scoresTensor.length) {
    averageScores[i] += scoresTensor[i] / howManyResults;
    ++i;
  }
}
```

and here is the log message during average loop process twice. In the first time, the scores array in `previousResults`  are the same  `[0.16993265, 0.15456167, 0.027866788, 0.107177936, 0.12646474, 0.053816866, 0.082612425, 0.059116375, 0.038425073, 0.06992877, 0.033074524, 0.07702225]` and this is not possible.

```
start avarage
previousResult(1520998400247): [[0.16993265, 0.15456167, 0.027866788, 0.107177936, 0.12646474, 0.053816866, 0.082612425, 0.059116375, 0.038425073, 0.06992877, 0.033074524, 0.07702225]]
previousResult(1520998400301): [[0.16993265, 0.15456167, 0.027866788, 0.107177936, 0.12646474, 0.053816866, 0.082612425, 0.059116375, 0.038425073, 0.06992877, 0.033074524, 0.07702225]]
previousResult(1520998400354): [[0.16993265, 0.15456167, 0.027866788, 0.107177936, 0.12646474, 0.053816866, 0.082612425, 0.059116375, 0.038425073, 0.06992877, 0.033074524, 0.07702225]]
previousResult(1520998400408): [[0.16993265, 0.15456167, 0.027866788, 0.107177936, 0.12646474, 0.053816866, 0.082612425, 0.059116375, 0.038425073, 0.06992877, 0.033074524, 0.07702225]]
previousResult(1520998400466): [[0.16993265, 0.15456167, 0.027866788, 0.107177936, 0.12646474, 0.053816866, 0.082612425, 0.059116375, 0.038425073, 0.06992877, 0.033074524, 0.07702225]]
previousResult(1520998400520): [[0.16993265, 0.15456167, 0.027866788, 0.107177936, 0.12646474, 0.053816866, 0.082612425, 0.059116375, 0.038425073, 0.06992877, 0.033074524, 0.07702225]]
previousResult(1520998400574): [[0.16993265, 0.15456167, 0.027866788, 0.107177936, 0.12646474, 0.053816866, 0.082612425, 0.059116375, 0.038425073, 0.06992877, 0.033074524, 0.07702225]]
previousResult(1520998400629): [[0.16993265, 0.15456167, 0.027866788, 0.107177936, 0.12646474, 0.053816866, 0.082612425, 0.059116375, 0.038425073, 0.06992877, 0.033074524, 0.07702225]]
previousResult(1520998400683): [[0.16993265, 0.15456167, 0.027866788, 0.107177936, 0.12646474, 0.053816866, 0.082612425, 0.059116375, 0.038425073, 0.06992877, 0.033074524, 0.07702225]]
previousResult(1520998400737): [[0.16993265, 0.15456167, 0.027866788, 0.107177936, 0.12646474, 0.053816866, 0.082612425, 0.059116375, 0.038425073, 0.06992877, 0.033074524, 0.07702225]]
....
....
start average
previousResult(1520998400301): [[0.14775836, 0.18298364, 0.026629224, 0.12195902, 0.111195154, 0.058891248, 0.07295453, 0.05453651, 0.04063993, 0.06559348, 0.032576166, 0.084282786]]
previousResult(1520998400354): [[0.14775836, 0.18298364, 0.026629224, 0.12195902, 0.111195154, 0.058891248, 0.07295453, 0.05453651, 0.04063993, 0.06559348, 0.032576166, 0.084282786]]
previousResult(1520998400408): [[0.14775836, 0.18298364, 0.026629224, 0.12195902, 0.111195154, 0.058891248, 0.07295453, 0.05453651, 0.04063993, 0.06559348, 0.032576166, 0.084282786]]
previousResult(1520998400466): [[0.14775836, 0.18298364, 0.026629224, 0.12195902, 0.111195154, 0.058891248, 0.07295453, 0.05453651, 0.04063993, 0.06559348, 0.032576166, 0.084282786]]
previousResult(1520998400520): [[0.14775836, 0.18298364, 0.026629224, 0.12195902, 0.111195154, 0.058891248, 0.07295453, 0.05453651, 0.04063993, 0.06559348, 0.032576166, 0.084282786]]
previousResult(1520998400574): [[0.14775836, 0.18298364, 0.026629224, 0.12195902, 0.111195154, 0.058891248, 0.07295453, 0.05453651, 0.04063993, 0.06559348, 0.032576166, 0.084282786]]
previousResult(1520998400629): [[0.14775836, 0.18298364, 0.026629224, 0.12195902, 0.111195154, 0.058891248, 0.07295453, 0.05453651, 0.04063993, 0.06559348, 0.032576166, 0.084282786]]
previousResult(1520998400683): [[0.14775836, 0.18298364, 0.026629224, 0.12195902, 0.111195154, 0.058891248, 0.07295453, 0.05453651, 0.04063993, 0.06559348, 0.032576166, 0.084282786]]
previousResult(1520998400737): [[0.14775836, 0.18298364, 0.026629224, 0.12195902, 0.111195154, 0.058891248, 0.07295453, 0.05453651, 0.04063993, 0.06559348, 0.032576166, 0.084282786]]
previousResult(1520998400791): [[0.14775836, 0.18298364, 0.026629224, 0.12195902, 0.111195154, 0.058891248, 0.07295453, 0.05453651, 0.04063993, 0.06559348, 0.032576166, 0.084282786]]
...
...
```

(2) According to the message log, you can see that the scores array corresponding to `1520998400301` at first time is `[0.16993265, 0.15456167, 0.027866788, 0.107177936, 0.12646474, 0.053816866, 0.082612425, 0.059116375, 0.038425073, 0.06992877, 0.033074524, 0.07702225]`, but in the next time, the scores array become `[0.14775836, 0.18298364, 0.026629224, 0.12195902, 0.111195154, 0.058891248, 0.07295453, 0.05453651, 0.04063993, 0.06559348, 0.032576166, 0.084282786]`

My second problem is that I don't know how could this happened. My code is identical with [RecognizeCommands.java](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/android/src/org/tensorflow/demo/RecognizeCommands.java). Any clues or advice would be very helpful, thank you.

Comment: Sorry, you probably want to explain your question. It is hard to understand what the problem is and what do you mean by "I notice that the results on average are identical and overwrite by the last result"

Comment: very appreciate your comment. I add more information. If there is any unclear part, please let me know. Thank you for your time.

Comment: This is an expected behavior. The recent values change outside of the loop, inside of the loop they should stay the same, you just calculate the average, you do not modify the value. Proper name for the array would be recentResults, not previousResults too.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. May I ask that comment is for question (1) or (2)?

Comment: If it is for (1), I understand that the values inside previousResults won't change in the for loop.  However, in this case, every (currentTimeMS, currentResults) pair should be very different, currentTimeMS should count up and currentResults which stand for the probabilities to each command should have variety scores. Therefore, my first question is asking that if the numbers shown in the loggings are the values to calculate the average. If the answer is no, I'd like to know the correct logging code.

Comment: If the answer is yes, I wondered how the score array changes its values which is the question(2).

Comment: Logging code is correct. Probability values might change between network evaluations, for example, if network remember the state. For example, with batch normalization. Second run remembers values from the first run and gives different score. If that is what you mean by "first time" and "second time".

Comment: Here are the probabilities scores when they enter recognizeCommands.processLatestResults. https://gist.github.com/NearLinHere/95a130bba508442c0b02652adf48ced9  I am not sure if the network will remember the state, but I am sure that the probability scores would be different in this case.

Comment: And here are the logs in each average process. https://gist.github.com/NearLinHere/40c4cd7ca4f3787adcbad871427565f3 Please check this image then you might be more understand my question: https://imgur.com/a/hmo6J I can tell that probability scores change every time (tab on the left side), but the scores are not the original values in the average loop(tab on the right side. I am wondering which part of code made this.

Comment: ok, I wrote you the answer

Comment: I would like to raise this issue on tensorflow Github. Would you like to tell me your Github account so that I could tag your name in the post? :)

Comment: Don't forget to provide the link to the issue here.

Comment: Here is the link https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/18082.

Comment: It is better to submit a pull request with code changes, not simply and issue. The way you wrote it will be simply ignored by the developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change this code:

```
  // Add the latest results to the head of the queue.
    previousResults.addLast(new Pair<Long, float[]>(currentTimeMS, currentResults));
```

As following:

```
  // Add the latest results to the head of the queue.
    previousResults.addLast(new Pair<Long, float[]>(currentTimeMS, 
                            Arrays.copyOf(currentResults, currentResults.length)));
```

Comment: Thank you very very very much! It works!!  May I ask what is the difference between these two methods?